# A problem with defining a norm to get a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. Let $\Lambda :X\to X$ be given by
$$\Lambda g=f_1(g)+f_2(g)+f_3(g),$$
where $f_i:X\to X$.
What I need to prove is that $\Lambda$ is a contraction. For some reason, I need to consider
$$\|\Lambda g_1-\Lambda g_2\|^2_X=\|(f_1(g_1)-f_1(g_2))+(f_2(g_1)-f_2(g_2))+(f_3(g_1)-f_3(g_2))\|_X^2.$$
The latter equality is very unconvinient for me, because of short multiplication formulas. Instead of this, can I understand a norm in a different way and consider
$$\|\Lambda g_1-\Lambda g_2\|^2_X=\|(f_1(g_1)-f_1(g_2))\|_X^2+\|(f_2(g_1)-f_2(g_2))\|_X^2+\|(f_3(g_1)-f_3(g_2))\|_X^2?$$

Comment: Without defining $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$ I doubt you can do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired equality will be in general false. True if the three differences  are mutually orthogonal. See [Pythagorean Theorem in Hilbert space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pythagorean_Theorem_(Hilbert_Space)). The usual procedure in this situation is using the [triangule inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).